# Calculate the minimum value from a nested embedded document from the last 7 days in MongoDB

Tags: javascript, database, mongodb, aggregation-framework, mongodb-compass

I have the following document in MongoDB

```json
{
    "product_id": "10001"
    "product_name": "Banana"
    "product_date": "2022-10-20T00:00:00.000+00:00"
    "product_price": 255.15
    "dates": {
        "2022-10-10": {
            "recorded_price": 195.15
        },
        "2022-10-15": {
            "recorded_price": 230.20
        },
        "2022-10-20": {
            "recorded_price": 255.20
        }
    }
}
```

I would like to add a new field named `"min_7day_price"` which would select the minimum price from the date object in the past 7 days.

Something like this:

```json
{
    "product_id": "10001"
    "product_name": "Banana"
    "product_date": "2022-10-20T00:00:00.000+00:00"
    "product_price": 255.15
    "dates": {
        "2022-10-10": {
            "recorded_price": 195.15
        },
        "2022-10-15": {
            "recorded_price": 230.20
        },
        "2022-10-20": {
            "recorded_price": 255.20
        }
    },
    "min_7day_price": 230.20
}
```

I tried using [aggregation](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation-pipeline/) to create a new field and convert the object to an array but I can't filter the values inside.

```json
{
  "min_7day_price": {
    $objectToArray: "$dates"
  }
}
```

Comment: Should `"product_date": "2022-10-20T00:00:00.000+00:00", "product_price": 255.15` be considered when determining `min_7day_price`?

Comment: For my needs it does not need to be considered, however it may help others if you propose a solution 

Comment: @nimrod-serok's answer looks like a good answer to your question then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to use update with pipeline:

1. Convert the dictionary to array
2. Use `$reduce` to keep only one item from it, by iterating and comparing the current item: `$$this` to the best item so far: `$$value`
3. Format the answer

```
db.collection.update({},
[
  {$set: {datesArr: {$objectToArray: "$dates"}}},
  {$set: {
      datesArr: {
        $reduce: {
          input: "$datesArr",
          initialValue: {
            k: {$dateAdd: {startDate: "$$NOW", amount: -7, unit: "day"}},
            v: {recorded_price: {$max: "$datesArr.v.recorded_price"}}
          },
          in: {
            $cond: [
              {$and: [
                  {$gte: [{$dateFromString: {dateString: "$$this.k"}}, "$$value.k"]},
                  {$lte: ["$$this.v.recorded_price", "$$value.v.recorded_price"]}
              ]},
              {
                k: {$dateFromString: {dateString: "$$this.k"}},
                v: "$$this.v.recorded_price"
              },
              "$$value"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {$set: {min_7day_price: "$datesArr.v", datesArr: "$$REMOVE"}}
])
```

See how it works on the [playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/15Wmr666ycK)

Comment: Thanks! But when I run this and have no values from the last 7 days, it keeps the initial value as an object. I modified it to be product_price as initial. [playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/pLQlYVs1gYY).